# Setting to send me an email when somone comments/answers?

Tags: discussion

Is there a setting to send me an email when someone comments on an "Answer" I posted? I poked around in my  profile settings, and didn't find anything.

I found a thread about removing the US Keyboard Layout from Windows 10. I couldn't comment because I have an awful reputation, so I answered instead.

By tomorrow I will have forgotten all about this (My wife is a relative of the author of the book "Before I go to sleep", so it runs in the family)

Comment: This ideally needs to be asked in meta, as for the setting I believe it's in https://superuser.com/users/email/settings/453560 -- inbox. However, you'll also get a notification on the bar at the top of the page.

Comment: @DavidPostill it's specific to Swifty's user.... tho it may not work I guess?

Comment: @djsmiley2k https://superuser.com/users/email/settings/current will always work for the current user - no user id required :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a setting to send me an email when someone comments on an "Answer" I posted? I poked around in my profile settings, and didn't find anything.

The email settings have just been changed (see [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)), but I believe the setting you are looking for is:

```
Inbox
Answers to your questions, comments, chat notifications, and more
```

You can select `Weekly`, `Daily`, `3 hrs`, or `Off`

Use [this link](https://superuser.com/users/email/settings/current) to edit your email settings.

---

> I found a thread about removing the US Keyboard Layout from Windows 10. I couldn't comment because I have an awful reputation, so I answered instead.

Please don't do that. **Answers that are not answers will be deleted.**

You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

As for the question/answer you are referring to, your (now deleted) answer looks more like a new question. Please [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing the other one for context if it helps).